# Insert records into Cloudera HDFS from c# application

Tags: c#, hdfs, cloudera, impala

I would know if exists a tool/framework to insert million records into a hdfs file from c# my application.

My application produces one record at time, and I want to be able to append this record in a file into hdfs, so that at the end I can use this file to populate impala table.

Thanks.

Comment: Look into running system level commands with C#. Then you can pass your records from your code to the standard in/out of the system and use HDFS file system commands to load the records.

Comment: can I have an example of code? Thanks

Comment: *"at the end"* means that you can create your million-records-CSV-file on your local Windows box, compress it with GZip, then dump it on HDFS all at once, right? The easiest way to transfer a file to HDFS from a non-Java app is to use WebHDFS **REST** interface. Provides no consistency check though, that's one of the reasons for using GZip (has some poor man's consistency check based on CRC32).